# Integrability of inverted Brownian Motion

Tags: expectation, brownian-motion, martingales, local-martingales

I'm trying to understand the counterexample to the claim that every $L^2$-bounded local martingale is also a true martingale. For this I'm considering the local martingale 
$$ X_t:=\frac{1}{\vert B_t + x \vert}, $$
where $B_t$ is a threedimensional Brownian Motion, $x\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$ and $|\cdot |$ denotes the euclidean norm.

In my calculations though, I have found $X_t$ to not even be integrable for a fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. My argument is as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[X_t\right]
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}^3}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|y-x|^{-1}\exp{(-\frac{|y|^2}{2t})}dy \\
&\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}^3}\int_{|y-x|\leq c}|y-x|^{-1}\exp{(-\frac{|y|^2}{2t})}dy \\
&\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}^3}\int_{|y-x|\leq c}|y-x|^{-1}\exp{(-\frac{(c+|x|)^2}{2t})}dy \\
&=k_c\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}^3}\int_{|y-x|\leq c}|y-x|^{-1}dy \\
&=k_c\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}^3}\int_{|y|\leq c}|y|^{-1}dy, \\
\end{align}
$$
where $c>0$ is arbitrary and $k_c$ is a constant only depending on $c$. To my knowledge, the last integral doesn't exist, and hence $\mathbb{E}\left[X_t\right]=\infty$

But this must be wrong, since $X_t \in L^2$. Any help to find my mistake would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful about the dimensions. The integral

$$\int_{\{y \in \color{red}{\mathbb{R}}; |y| \leq c\}} \frac{1}{|y|} \, dy$$

is infinite, but the integral

$$\int_{\{y \in \color{red}{\mathbb{R}^3}; |y| \leq c\}} \frac{1}{|y|} \, dy$$

is finite (and **this** is the integral which appears in your calculation). This follows from the following well known statement:

> The integral $$\int_{\{y \in \mathbb{R}^k; |y| \leq c\}} \frac{1}{|y|^{\alpha}} \, dy$$ is finite if, and only if, $\alpha<k$.

Comment: The boxed statement is easily checked using polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Polar coordinates work really well for three dimensions. Do you also use them to prove the statement for arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: @amars Well, yes, there are also polar coordinates for higher dimensions. Using these polar coordinates it is possible to show that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \varphi(|x|) \, dx = k \omega_k \int_{(0,\infty)} r^{k-1} \phi(r) \, dr$$ where $\omega_k$ is the surface of the $(k-1)$-dimensional unit sphere, and this easily gives the result which I mentioned in my answer.